# OpenGL stencil pipe

Tags: opengl, stencil

Is there a document **describing 2D stencil pipe** ?
Static, no rotation etc.

Something in more details then

enable stencil (buffer) 
write stencil ( mask) to stencil buffer
1st pass 
write stencil object to stencil buffer
....
setup stencil function
2nd pass 
write object to be analyzed

Comment: To find existing documents, you should ask a search engine. Just linking to other docs isn't what we do here. When asking here, you should instead focus on the problem that you hope the document would help you solve. What's the specific question you're hoping to find an answer to inside such a document? Edit your question to ask that, with as much context about your game as you can provide. With those details, we can give you targeted, high-quality answers tailored to what you need.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the post, it for sure answered my question,
appreciate that very much.

In the spirit of KISS, kindly allow me to translate to less fancy English

1. Google it
2. RTFM

Many thanks , problem solved.